# Соединение таблиц в mysql, как лучше?

Tags: mysql

Добрый день.
Нужно соединить 4 таблицы. Какой из этих вариантов предпочтительнее?

```
1 таблица:
id | имя | id_2й_таблицы | id_3й_таблицы | id_4й_таблицы

2, 3 и 4 таблицы:
id | информация
```

и соединять с 1й таблицы ко всем, думаю вы поняли - но дам пример:
(от **1** таблицы **id_2й_таблицы** = **id** **2**й таблицы).

Или такой вариант:

```
1 таблица:
id | имя

2 таблица (3 и 4 по аналогии)
id_2й_таблицы | информация
```

И присоединять 2, 3 и 4 таблицы по id_'N'й_таблицы к id первой таблицы?
Пример: **id_2й_таблицы** **2** таблицы = **id 1** таблицы)

Какой вариант оптимальнее и быстрее будет выполняться?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

К первой таблице,которая содержит айдишники других присоединяете через LEFT JOIN например остальные таблицы

Comment: а я все-таки надеялся что второй вариант будет лучше)  
но если честно, я просто не знаю как их соединить в первом случае. не подскажите? вот так я сделал второй вариант:  
  
    SELECT i.image_id FROM images i
    INNER JOIN gender g ON g.image_id=i.image_id
    INNER JOIN age a ON a.image_id=i.image_id
    INNER JOIN location l ON l.image_id=i.image_id
        WHERE g.mof=0
            AND a.age BETWEEN 28 AND 25
            AND l.country='USA'
                ORDER BY RAND()
                LIMIT 0,2